# How to use newline character in text in cmd batch?

Tags: svn, batch-file

I would like to do

```
svn commit -m "<message>"
```

But message should have two lines:

```
Commit by: firstuser
Bug track: 9283
```

How to add new line character into message? I've tried SHIFT+ENTER, CTRL+T but it does not work. I use MS cmd command line.

Comment: Show us your batch file, at least the relevant part, so we can help.

Comment: svn commit --message "Commit by: firstuser<new_line>Bug track: 9283" - This is my batch file. And the problem is how to put new line so that it will work

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about using the `-F` parameter to get the log message from a file?

Then, you could do this (untested):

```
ECHO Commit by: firstuser>SvnLog.txt
ECHO Bug track: 9283>>SvnLog.txt

SVN COMMIT -F SvnLog.txt
```

Comment: Looks like it's only solution

Comment: There's another option if you can use PowerShell (see my answer)

Answer (score 12):

I found the answer over at Serverfault:

```
svn ci -m $'This is the first line\nThis is the second line'
```

Apparently it's a [shell-problem](https://serverfault.com/questions/148917/use-linefeed-or-carriage-return-in-subversion-commit-message-from-the-command-lin).

Comment: This does not work with cmd.exe in Windows since the solution is based on linux shell doing the job not svn client.
However the thread you referenced made me think and find another option.

Comment: This works well under linux, although it only works with $' not $" so ensure the string is only single quoted.

Comment: Your answer only applies to linux

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem and while Claes Mogren's answer does not work with cmd.exe it made me think if there's a shell on Windows that could do that.
And of course there is... PowerShell.

Using PowerShell shell you can achieve this using following command:

```
svn ci -m "reference to Ninject fixed`nsome ignores added"
```

Notice the combination of backqoute and n in the message

```
`n
```

Answer (score 6):

To create a newline in a svn message the best way is the one of aphoria with an extra message-file.

But it can be done also with the `-m`

Sample with a batch file

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set lf=^


rem ** Two empty lines are neccessary for creating the Linefeed
svn commit -m "A!lf!Message!lf!with!LF!newline"
```

You could also use it on the command line

```
svn commit -m ^"This is a^
MORE?
MORE?my newline"
```

Answer (score 5):

You can define the newline as follows:

```
set newline=^& echo.
```

Then, you can use the newline in other statements, like this: (no quotes)

```
echo This is the first line%newline%This is the second line
echo "This is the first line"%newline%"This is the second line"
```

or with an extra caret, like this:

```
set text=This is the first line^%newline%This is the second line
```

Perhaps you can play with that, but mind the combination with quotes!

Comment: The above will most probably **not** work within parameters for **svn**. It _can_ work within parameters for other batch scripts, depending on how those scripts treat them (possibly extra carets needed) — definitely not advisable, though.

Comment: In some cases it behaves like a newline, but it doesn't create a newline-character in the variable. You can test it with `set newline` to see the real content.

Comment: That is because the "& echo." is just passed along until it gets interpreted (or not).

Comment: @jeb: [Your solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/721251/how-to-use-newline-character-in-text-in-cmd-batch/5557582#5557582) behaves better, with less quote/caret problems :) but I have not actually verified either method with svn.

Comment: I tested my version and it works, your version can't work, as (you said it) it simply expands to `& echo` so the line is split into two different commands, however it's an interessting way to echo a newline

Answer (score 5):

Just write `svn ci -m "old line` press <kbd>Enter</kbd> then type in next line `new line"`

[image: Example]

This is much easier than using file.

Comment: @LukasIgnatavičius, I didn't know there is a `Enter` Key on keyboard! Question is asking how to do it in batch or **`*.bat`** file, look at question tags. pressing Enter does not work in batch files! in case you haven't heard of [batch files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file)

Answer (score 1):

I use the following method and it works:

```
svn commit {list of files to commit}
```

After typing the above command and pressing enter, an editor will open. Write your comment there and exit the editor. Upon exiting the editor, the commit command will execute and whatever you wrote in the editor will be committed too.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that "enter" (Ascii 13) sends the command. So you need a "newline"

use alt + 10  (press alt, type the number at the numberblock, release alt)

Comment: I've tried it. I have new line in command window, but SVN gets only first line.

Answer (score 0):

This works for us:

private static final char LF = (char) 13;

```
setMessage("Test"  + LF + "Jij" + LF + "Dit" + LF + "Effe");
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the message in text editor and just copy and paste it to terminal(command editor).

1. Just type message in a text editor in multiple lines.

   -m "Message line

   Message line 2

   Message line 3"
2. Type the required command in command editor.

   svn command
3. Copy and paste the message content from text editor  to  command editor.

   svn command -m "Message line 1.

   Message line 2

   Message line 3"

4.Execute Enter .

5.It works :)

Answer (score 0):

Additional example to @jeb's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5557582/9947141)

answer:

```
set br= ^
<</br (newline)>>
<</br>>
```

example:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableExtensions enableDelayedExpansion
rem cd /D "%~dp0"
set br= ^


rem br, can't be saved to a var. by using %..%;


set "t=t1!br!t2!br!t3"

for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%q in ('!t!') do (
    echo %%q
)


:scIn
rem endlocal
pause
rem exit /b
```

; output:

```
t1
t2
t3
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating file from cmd with text that needs to be inputted.

Try this

1. Open CMD
2. Enter echo "This is the first line" @echo. "This is the second line" > textfile.bat

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

echo Message1 & echo Message2 & echo Message3