# SVN commit with a newline in message

Tags: svn, newline, message, commit

I am trying to to an svn commit with a new line in message

how can i do this newline? I have tried

```
svn commit -m "Issue \n solution" file.js
```

but it didnt work obviously.

Comment: If you want to do that from command line, you can use powershell:    
PS C:\temp> svn commit -m "Issue `n solution" file.js

Answer (score 23, accepted):

alternatively, just do not specify `-m` (and not `-F`) and you will be shown an editor where you can type your message:

> Send changes from your working copy to the repository. If you do not
>   supply a log message with your commit by using either the --file (-F)
>   or --message (-m) option, svn will launch your editor for you to
>   compose a commit message. See the editor-cmd list entry in the section
>   called “Config”.

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.commit.html

Comment: great I could help. please mark it as an accepted answer, so future readers will have some indications what works. full disclosure: i will receive some karma for that :)

Comment: Thanks, I got the following message: svn: E205007: None of the environment variables SVN_EDITOR, VISUAL or EDITOR are set, and no 'editor-cmd' run-time configuration option was found but I solved with this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169241/why-cant-i-use-the-svn-editor-environment-variable-in-cygwin

Comment: I used in CLI: "export SVN_EDITOR=subl" and now I use sublime to edit my commit messages when I need multiline

Comment: There is another answer easier without use another editor, pls view it http://stackoverflow.com/a/26548248/5315714

Comment: Example usage:

svn commit -F pathToFile.extension

Answer (score 5):

> --file (-F) FILENAME
>
> ```
> Uses the contents of the named file for the specified subcommand.
> ```
>
> Different subcommands do different things with this content. For
>   example, svn commit uses the content as a commit log message, whereas
>   svn propset uses it as a property value.

Comment: svn commit -F path_to_file.extension